# router.attach(String, Class<? extends ServerResource>) not working properly

Tags: java

OK, I have made some progress since my original problem question post.  Here's the new  scenario

```
  Server server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, new TestServerApplication());
  server.start()

  Here's the code that's in the client
  ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(
            "http://localhost:8182/contacts/123");
```

**The following code does NOT work**

```
router.attach("/contacts/123", ContactServerResource.class);
 Exception in thread "main" Not Found (404) - Not Found
```

**The following code does NOT work**

```
router.attach("/contacts/123", ContactServerResource.class, Router.MODE_BEST_MATCH);
 Exception in thread "main" Not Found (404) - Not Found
```

***** using attachDefault results in the call being handled properly

```
// success!
router.attachDefault(ContactServerResource.class);
```

I also tried something different rather than using a Server.

```
Component component = new Component();

// Add a new HTTP server listening on port 8182.
component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

// Attach the sample application.
component.getDefaultHost().attach("/contacts/123",
        new TestServerApplication());

component.start();
```

In this case `router.attach("/contacts/123", ContactServerResource.class)` is still called and it still fails to work.  You have to `attachDefault()` to get it to work

I can't think of anything else to try.  Anybody have any ideas?  thank you